# How to write binary data into files in Java?

Tags: java, io, filestream, binaryfiles, java-io

Is there a way to store some values in a binary file as C# does?

For example in C# it would be:

```
BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(MyFilStream);
bw.Write(data...);
```

And then, to read it like

```
BinaryReader br = new bla bla...;
br.ReadInt(file);
```

Is there a way to do this in Java? I'm Reading a lot of binary reading in Google, but I just find something of a JPG file, don't get it...

Comment: Check `Serializable`, `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream`.

Comment: [Google: java binary file io](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=java+binary+file+io), [second entry](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=245) ;)

Comment: Yes, you can write (and read) binary data. I suggest you look at [`DataOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make use of [`DataOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html) and/or [`DataInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) to store and read binary data in Java.

Here is an example of how it's done:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Test{
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException{

        DataInputStream d = new DataInputStream(new 
                                 FileInputStream("test.txt"));

        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(new 
                                 FileOutputStream("test1.txt"));

        String count;
        while((count = d.readLine()) != null){
            String u = count.toUpperCase();
            System.out.println(u);
            out.writeBytes(u + "  ,");
        }
        d.close();
        out.close();
    }
}
```

> Editors' note:
>
> `.close()` statements should be wrapped in `finally` block:
>
> ```
> finally {
>     d.close();
>     out.close();
> }
> ```

> Source:
>   http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_dataoutputstream.htm

Comment: You should make sure you close your streams in a `finally` block.